# Can not connect remotely to a second instance of SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In a server I have 2 instances, the first that is the default called `SQLCompart` on TCP port 1433 and the second called `AISLANTES` on TCP port 1435.

When I try to connect remotely to `SQLCOMPART` it works successfully, but just with the ip (it doesn't connect with named instance `<IP>\<INSTANCE>`).

So the problem here is that I can't connect remotely to `AISLANTES`.

I am trying with `<IP>, <PORT>` also with `<IP>\<INSTANCE>` and with `<IP>\<INSTANCE>, <PORT>`

The firewall inbound rule for tcp port 1435 is enabled.

What am I missing?

SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image]

SQL Server Configuration Manager TCP/IP properties

[image]

this is the error that i get 
[SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihMfv.png)
[SQLCMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz6zX.png)

Comment: What are you using to connect?  Show us the actual connect string or text of the one that works and the one that doesn’t work.  Also the tool and/or code you are connecting with.  Finally, what error message do you receive?

Comment: I edit the post with the images of the error, i am using SQL Server Management Studio and also tried with sqlcmd with command line

Comment: Edit your images to hide your password, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- Port was changed, but instance was not restarted
- Multiple firewalls and port 1435 is not opened on all of them
- TCP for a second instance not enabled at all

Consider to check your latest SQL Server log and find something like:

```
2018-04-09 18:53:11.95 spid11s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ].
2018-04-09 18:53:11.95 spid11s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\sql\query ].
2018-04-09 18:53:11.97 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
2018-04-09 18:53:11.97 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
```

So you will know for sure on which port SQL Server listens for incoming connections

p.s. if SQL instance installed on domain controller, it cannot use NETWORK_SERVICE as an account